# Macro does not automatically run when cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to run a macro when a value in cell **F1** is updated by the calculation **=DAYS360(B2,B1)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$F$1" Then
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
End If
End Sub
```

There are several topics on this, and none of the solutions for them are working for me.. I am  baffled. If I manually change the value in cell **F1**, the macro runs. However, when I add a new value in the date column that causes the calculation in cell **F1** to update, nothing happens.

Some of the other topics offer solutions using the **intersect** function, however, those are giving me the same results.

Comment: change `Worksheet_Change` to `Worksheet_Calculate`

Comment: +1, nice one, was looking for something like this myself

Comment: When I use Calculate in place of Change, I get a compile error. "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name" - any suggestions?

Comment: use `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` - without parametr

Comment: @simoco Than how does he know if the cell he is interested in was the one that calculated or not?

Comment: Yes, this function works, but for any cell that is recalculated. I am fortunate in this case, that this is the only cell on the sheet with a calculation, however, I would like to make this cell specific, as I will be adding more in the future.

Comment: @DLittlejohn412 Have you tested my answer yet? Was is not what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your Change Event to look for the cells that F1 is looking at.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
End If
End Sub
```

This makes perfect sense because these are actually the cells that you are changing, i caught this from your line `when I add a new value in the date column that causes the calculation in cell F1 to update`

Alternativly if your formula references will change you can use the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("F1").Precedents
    If Target.Address = r.Address Then
        MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

What the above code will do is whenever any cell in the worksheet is changed, it will goto cell F1, then look to see if the cell that was changed was one of the cells the F1 relies on for its calculation, if it wasn't it does nothing, if it was, than it will fire the msgbox.

***UPDATE:*** Another option that will work across all the sheets to see if any cell changed is relied on by the formula inside the Cell F1 on Sheet1 when the cells are on another page can be found below.

```
Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo NextStep
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("F1").Precedents
    If Target.Address = r.Address Then
        MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
        Exit For
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next r

NextStep:
If InStr(Replace(Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("F1").Formula, "'", ""), sh.Name + "!" + Target.Address) _
   Or InStr(Replace(Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("F1").Formula, "'", ""), sh.Name + "!" + Target.Address(False)) _
   Or InStr(Replace(Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("F1").Formula, "'", ""), sh.Name + "!" + Target.Address(, False)) _
   Or InStr(Replace(Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("F1").Formula, "'", ""), sh.Name + "!" + Target.Address(False, False)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
End If
End Sub
```

If it needs to work both on other sheets and the current sheet, then you will have to add another if test for target in the formula then see if it is preceded by the name of a sheet in the workbook and a `!`

***UPDATE2:*** Both the above are slightly flawed (as Simoco has pointed out) the last thing I can come up with is to use a public variable, to set the value of your cell and every time the Work Sheet is calculated to test if the value changed. (if doing a whole column you may need to Dim a collection or array to test against)

So inside you worksheet module, replace your original code with the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public F1ValueOld As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("F1").Value <> F1ValueOld Then
        MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
        F1ValueOld = Range("F1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This will work while the workbook is open, but you will get an error when you close and reopen the workbook, so inside the Workbook module add the following code also:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    F1ValueOld = Sheets("SheetF1IsOn").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

This should no accomplish what you are attempting.

Comment: `.Precedents` gives precedents only from _active sheet_. If formula in `F1` would be `=Sheet2!B2` your approach won't work

Comment: @simoco Approuch would work (test all cells formula is relying on), just would have to use regex to extract ranges from the cells formula, defiantly would be more work though and might not be something you'd want fired every time a cell is changed, but could work. Either way my theory was based of his formula in his question `=DAYS360(B2,B1)`

Comment: it may be a particular case `=DAYS360(B2,B1)`. For `=Sheet2!B2` if cell `B2` changed, your event woudn't even be fired (since changed cell in another sheet)

Comment: +1, much better, but 1) also add 4 additional `OR` with `"'" & sh.Name + "'!"`  ( or even better replace `'` from formual) 2) doesn't work in case when `F1` has formula `=SUM(Sheet2!B1:B5)` and changed `B3`

Comment: sorry for confusing you, but it's better to remove `'` from formula and then make `InStr()`, since for sheet names without spaces you should use `sh.Name & "!"`, while for sheets with spaces `"'" & sh.Name + "'!"`

Comment: @simoco I went another route =), everything in code depends on actual usage though, I still think my first option is best in many cases.

Comment: Good! For many cells you can use Dictionary to store values with keys - addresses

Comment: @simoco A collection should work as well, and won't require the outside reference.

Comment: @user2140261 ; The **UPDATE 2** code appears to be working correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @simoco and user2140261: Thank you both for all the work and contribution. I'm sorry I was not online looking at this while you were, as I would have added another detail that may have saved some time. The `=DAYS360(B2,B1)` uses **B1** `=TODAY()` and **B2** `=MAX(Sheet1!A:A)`. The idea being that cell **F1** will change every day, automatically, regardless if the user enters a new value in the workbook at all.